# Access violation Error in IAP Simulation

Tags: windows-phone, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add IAP to a windows phone 8.1 app. I am currently trying to test it by using the WMAPPMANIFEST.

I can run code to get the listings from the file successfully, but whenever i try to simulate buying a product, the application crashes with the error

*Exception thrown at 0x69E02F47 (Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.TestingFramework.dll) in G.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*

Has someone experienced this error before, what is the solution?